# Generic term for the other party to an aggressor's actions

Tags: single-word-requests

In a confrontation between two parties, where one is being aggressive towards another (**either** by attacking them **or** by simply posturing and frightening the other), one side could be referred to as the "aggressor", but what could the other be called? I'm looking for a one-word description if possible.

"Victim" sounds too strong a word for simply being intimidated and backing away from the confrontation, and the only other term I can come up with, "target" seems too vague.

Example: The aggressor [attacked / intimidated] the ______. Then the _____ ran away.

Comment: It's often [*the **target** of his aggression.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+target+of+his+aggression%22) But [***victim***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+victim+of+his+aggression%22) is significantly more common.

Comment: A party to a crime or wrongful deed is someone who joins in the deed. A victim of aggression is not a party to it.

Comment: As suggested by the other comments, *victim* is a reasonable word (and the most likely).

Answer (score 1):

It's ''***AGGRESSEE***''.

According to Oxford Living Dictionary:

***aggressee***

NOUN

A person, nation, etc. towards whom or which aggression is directed; 
the object of an attack.

Opposed to aggressor.

There's an example from Reverso.context.net:

''Thus, I think things are very clear here as to who is the aggressor and who is the ***aggressee***, who has the truth and who does not''.

Comment: Not what I would call a generic term. It seems to barely exist at all, and mostly in behavioral sciences texts. According to Eliphind.com, it appears about 8 times in American newspapers since 1890, and one of the writers in 1935 thought he had just coined it. And I have never heard of any of the newspapers in which it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Such an array of terms that could be used here.  For starters, ***mark*** would fit the bill:

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mark?src=search-dict-hed)
>
> ***mark*** - an object of attack, ridicule, or abuse specifically : a victim or
> prospective victim of a swindle

The word ***prey*** would also work:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prey)
>
> ***prey*** - one that is helpless or unable to resist attack : VICTIM